# Search on edittext for recycle view

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview

I have created  search view using  edit text, but it didn't work. My Edit text is in dialog fragment .I  have tried to move my code to onCreate() but then my app get force close. The edit text should search recycle view item.

And it should be automatically search without clicking any button.

[image]

This is my code for search.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@OnClick(R.id.button_choose)
void chooseLOV() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lov_kodepos, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rv_lov_kodepos);
    final EditText search  = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_lov_search);

    API.getKodePos().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<KodePos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<KodePos>> call, Response<ArrayList<KodePos>> response) {
            if (response.code()== 200){
                Log.i("bella", "onResponse: "+response);

                data = response.body();
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(AddCustomerActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(AddCustomerActivity.this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new KodePosAdapter(data));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<KodePos>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AddCustomerActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(AddCustomerActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            et_kodepos.setText(data.get(position).getPosKode());
            et_kota.setText(data.get(position).getPosKota());
            et_provinsi.setText(data.get(position).getPosProp());
            et_kecamatan.setText(data.get(position).getPosCamat());
            et_kelurahan.setText(data.get(position).getPosLurah());

            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }));

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ArrayList<KodePos> kodePos = new ArrayList<>();
            if(tempDatass!=null){
                for (KodePos kodePos1:data){p
                    String dat = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (kodePos1.getPosCamat().toLowerCase().contains(dat)){
                        kodePos.add(kodePos1);
                    }
                }
                tempDatass = kodePos;
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new KodePosAdapter(tempDatass));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What is `tempDatass`? Are you sure it's not null in `onTextChanged()`? Looks like you don't really need it at all, anyway.

Comment: its a array list model @MikeM, then should i remove it ?

Comment: Well, whatever it is to begin with, it's not being used there, because you discard it, and set it to `kodePos`. That is, it's kinda pointless there.

Comment: i've remove it . still didn't work for me

Comment: @MikeM. hi mike now my code is corect. But i want to ask you about how to get an item base on what did i search

Comment: Oh, yeah, it looks like that's what you were trying to do with `tempDatass`. In `onTextChanged()`, you need to keep reference to the filtered `ArrayList`, and call `get(position)` on that in `onItemClick()`, instead of on `data`. So go back to what you had originally, but just remove the `if(tempDatass!=null)`, and replace all of the `data.get(position)` calls in `onItemClick()` to `tempDatass.get(position)`. Sorry about that. I didn't see what you were trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

I Just solve my problem like this. first i declare my model

```
 public ArrayList<KodePos> data;

 public ArrayList<KodePos> tempData;
```

Then in the recycle view i add this

```
 data = response.body();
 tempData = data;
```

After that i the text changed i code like this

```
 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ArrayList<KodePos> kodePos = new ArrayList<>();
            if (tempData!=null){
                for (KodePos kodePosSatu: data ){
                    String dat = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (kodePosSatu.getPosCamat().toLowerCase().contains(dat)) {
                        kodePos.add(kodePosSatu);
                    }
                }
                tempData = kodePos;
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new KodePosAdapter(tempData));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

and it works fine :)